# Change position of key of an array

Tags: php, arrays

The following code will print "com, net, org, biz".

I want to print "net, com, org, biz".
Basically, to set the first array using the $chosen variable.

```
<?php
$array = array('com', 'net', 'org', 'biz');

$chosen = 'net';

$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $value) {
    $newArray = $value;
}

print_r($newArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array('com', 'net', 'org', 'biz');

foreach($array as $value) 
{

  print_r($value);

}

?>
```

It simply all the itme of the $arry contains.....